# Search in array with high dimensions having specific properties

Tags: algorithm

I have a 3D array in which values are monotonic. How to find all (x,y), |f(X,Y,Z) – v1| < t.

Comment: Is f(x,y,z) continuous and differentiable along the 3 axes? Or in other words, do you have an option to calculate, say, f(x+1,y,z) given the value of f(x,y,z) via a possibly-not-so-expensive operation?

Comment: Can you delegate to another core, processor or thread?  For example, with 2 threads, thread one calculates over the odd Z locations and thread 2 calculates over the even Z locations.  There are probably other algorithms to assist in parallel execution.

Comment: Are you looking for a Java solution?  There are libraries, e.g. Boost, for thread support in C++.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews currently I am working on this problem as part of a bigger project in java. I can use threads in java. Thats not an issue. Can you suggest in what other places of this algorithm can I use threading to speedup this computation other than the one you already suggested?

Comment: You should have two paths of research:  reduce the quantity of operations and parallel computing.  There libraries for using the Graphics Processor cores, if you can figure out how to divide the problem into distinct operations that can be performed in parallel.  Good candidates are matrix operations.  Search for "CUDA Matrix Operations C++".

Answer (score 2):

There are Omega(n^2) points whose coordinates sum to n - 1. Nothing is known a priori about how the values of these points compare to each other, so, in the worst case, all of them must be inspected. An upper bound that matches up to constant factors is provided by running the 2D algorithm in each constant-z slice.

Comment: @TheGame = O(n^2), yes. The constants may see some improvement, so wait a while to mark a best answer.

Answer (score 1):

For each value (eg. `v1`), execute the following steps:

1. Execute the 2D algorithm for the 4 cube faces tangent to the X axis (Y=0, Y=n-1, Z=0, Z=n-1). Index the resulting set of matching (X, Y, Z) cells by X coordinate for the next step.
2. Execute the 2D algorithm for all n slices along the X axis (X=0..n-1), using the result of step 1 to initialize the first boundary point for the 2D algorithm. If there are no matching cells for the given x coordinate, move on to the next slice in constant time.

Worst case complexity will be O(O(2D algorithm) * n).

For multiple values (`v2`, etc.) keep a cache of function evaluations, and re-execute the algorithm for each value. For 100^3, a dense array would suffice.

It might be useful to think of this as an isosurface extraction algorithm, though your monotonicity constraint makes it easier.

Comment: In step 1, by Y=0 I meant the 2D slice in the XZ plane that has all Y coordinates equal to 0. This slice intersects the first X-slice on a line (Y=0 and X=0) - so if the first step found a matching cell on this line, it could be used as a starting point for the next step. By searching all 4 faces tangent to X, all matching cells on the perimeter of X=0 are known prior to step 2 - so we know whether there are any matching cells in that slice. If there were, the 2D algorithm can start from the those cells (rather than searching the perimeter again for a starting point).

Answer (score 1):

If the 3d array is monotonically non-decreasing in each dimension then we know that if

```
f(x0, y0, z0) < v1 - t
          or
f(x1, y1, z1) > v1 + t
```

then no element of the sub-array `f(x0...x1, y0...y1, z0...z1)` can contain any interesting point. To see this consider for example that

```
f(x0, y0, z0) <= f(x, y0, z0) <= f(x, y, z0) <= f(x, y, z)
```

holds for each `(x, y, z)` of the sub-array, and a similar relation holds (with reversed direction) for `(x1, y1, z1)`. Thus `f(x0, y0, z0)` and `f(x1, y1, z1)` are the minimum and maximum value of the sub-array, respectively.

A simple search approach can then be implemented by using a recursive subdivision scheme:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename CBack>
int values(Mat3<T>& data, T v0, T v1, CBack cback,
           int x0, int y0, int z0, int x1, int y1, int z1) {
    int count = 0;
    if (x1 - x0 <= 2 && y1 - y0 <= 2 && z1 - z0 <= 2) {
        // Small block (1-8 cells), just scan it
        for (int x=x0; x<x1; x++) {
            for (int y=y0; y<y1; y++) {
                for (int z=z0; z<z1; z++) {
                    T v = data(x, y, z);
                    if (v >= v0 && v <= v1) cback(x, y, z);
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        T va = data(x0, y0, z0), vb = data(x1-1, y1-1, z1-1);
        count += 2;
        if (vb >= v0 && va <= v1) {
            int x[] = {x0, (x0 + x1) >> 1, x1};
            int y[] = {y0, (y0 + y1) >> 1, y1};
            int z[] = {z0, (z0 + z1) >> 1, z1};
            for (int ix=0; ix<2; ix++) {
                for (int iy=0; iy<2; iy++) {
                    for (int iz=0; iz<2; iz++) {
                        count += values<T, CBack>(data, v0, v1, cback,
                                                  x[ix], y[iy], z[iz],
                                                  x[ix+1], y[iy+1], z[iz+1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The code basically accepts a sub-array and simply skips the search if the lowest element is too big or the highest element is too small, and splits the array in 8 sub-cubes otherwise. The recursion ends when the sub-array is small (2x2x2 or less) and a full scan is performed in this case.

Experimentally I found that with this quite simple approach an array with 100x200x300 elements generated by setting element `f(i,j,k)` to `max(f(i-1,j,k), f(i,j-1,k), f(i,j,k-1)) + random(100)` can be searched for the middle value and t=1 checking only about 3% of the elements (25 elements checked for each element found within range).

```
Data 100x200x300 = 6000000 elements, range [83, 48946]
Looking for [24594-1=24593, 24594+1=24595]
Result size = 6850 (5.4 ms)
Full scan = 6850 (131.3 ms)
Search count = 171391 (25.021x, 2.857%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is non-decreasing, I think you can do something with binary searches.
Inside a `(x, 1, 1)` (column) vector you can do a binary search to find the range that matches your requirement which would be `O(log(n))`.
To find which column vectors to look in you can do a binary search over `(x, y, 1)` (slices) vectors checking just the first and last points to know if the value can fall in them which will take again `O(log(n))`.
To know which slices to look in you can binary search the whole cube checking the 4 points (`(0, 0), (x, 0), (x, y), (0, y)`) which would take `O(log(n))`.
So in total, the algorithm will take `log(z) + a * log(y) + b * log(x)` where `a` is the number of matching slices and `b` is the number of matching columns.
Naively calculating the worst case is `O(y * z * log(x))`.